# 'module' object has no attribute 'interpld'

Tags: python, module

I'm fresh on python,using python2.7,and got some questions on the code blew:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import pylab as py

x=np.r_[0:10:11j]
y=np.sin(x)
xnew=np.r_[0:10:100j]

#f=interpolate.interpld(x,y)


py.figure(1)
py.clf()
py.plot(x,y,'ro')
for kind in ['nearest','zero','slinear','quadtatic','cublic']:
    f=interpolate.interpld(x,y,kind=kind)
    ynew=f(xnew)
    py.plot(xnew,ynew,label=kind)
py.legend(loc='lower right')
```

but it resulted in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LCL\.xy\startups\python_web\my_first_try_on_python_web\python_Interpolation\example1.py", line 22, in <module>
    f=interpolate.interpld(x,y,kind=kind)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'interpld'
```

Comment: What does `print scipy.interpolate.__file__` say?

Comment: it says:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.pyc

Comment: At least you didn't mix up modules then. But as the answers below point out, you misspelled some things.

Answer (score 3):

You used `interpld`, i.e. `INTERPLD`.

You want `interp1d`, i.e. with the numeral `1`, for one-dimensional.

Comment: I fixed it just now,but here came another question:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LCL\.xy\startups\python_web\my_first_try_on_python_web\python_Interpolation\example1.py", line 22, in <module>
    f=interpolate.interp1d(x,y,kind=kind)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 272, in __init__
    "routines for other types." % kind)
NotImplementedError: quadtatic is unsupported: Use fitpack routines for other types.

Comment: Again, you probably mean `quadratic`, not `quadtatic`.

Comment: .. and `cublic` should be `cubic`.  You can see the list of allowed values in the documentation (`help(interpolate.interp1d)`).

Comment: Oh,I learn from the youtube video,and what a careless man I am,thank you for indicating

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `interpolate.interpld` but the function name is `interpolate.interp1d` (with a number one instead of a letter L).

Comment: I fixed it just now,but here came another question:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LCL\.xy\startups\python_web\my_first_try_on_python_web\python_Interpolation\example1.py", line 22, in <module>
    f=interpolate.interp1d(x,y,kind=kind)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 272, in __init__
    "routines for other types." % kind)
NotImplementedError: quadtatic is unsupported: Use fitpack routines for other types.

Comment: @ray: Do you mean "quadratic" instead of "quadtatic"?

Comment: Oh,I learn from the youtube video,and what a careless man I am,thank you for indicating

Answer (score 1):

It should be "interp1d",the number 1,not L

Comment: What do you mean by "it"? Can you explain that further?